# Background Video covers the rest of the page in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, video

So I have a video playing in the background of a splash page, it is running on a loop with no available controls and I have text and an image sitting on top of it. I set it up as a  with z-index: -100.

This works perfectly in Safari and Firefox, but in Chrome and Opera when the page loads everything on top of the video disappears. As soon as I resize the window everything re-appears, but when I refresh it has the same problem.

I'm not really sure what to try at this point or if this is a common problem. Any help would be great, we're trying to launch the site tomorrow.

Edit: Here's a link to the site. I was hoping this was a common enough problem that there would be a well known fix. http://jessemacdesign.com/upload/splash.html

Comment: Where is your code ? We are not wizards

Comment: Here's a link to the site. I was hoping this was a common enough problem that there would be a well known fix. http://jessemacdesign.com/upload/splash.html

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? I cant replicate it on v36.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it's working in Chrome and Opera no problem (so check you don't need an update!). However, I wouldn't recommend using negative z-index as there's not really any point in doing so. Try this for your z-index and see if it works:

```
video#bgvid {
z-index: 1;
}
#bgimg {
z-index: 1;
}
```

I would also remove the z-index from #main as I don't feel it's needed.

Failing all of the above, try structuring your page differently so your video is in it's own div. I can't recreate your issue myself though, it's working in Chrome and Opera for me.

**Original:** Any chance of a link? It would be hard for me to help you without viewing the code directly!

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean the black 'border' above and below the video? The video, header text and footer are displaying fine for me on Chrome and Opera but the black top-bottom border disappears.

Comment: Ok, there was a glitch in my code that I fixed and forgot to re-upload. Check it out now. In my Chrome everything disappears besides the video. I tried clearing my cache and resetting the browser to make sure it's nothing on my end.

Comment: My bad, only just started using Stack Overflow. Noted for in future. Cheers Andrew!

Edit: I'll edit my answer once I have one...

Comment: Updating Chrome absolutely fixed it. I will remove the z-index from main, that was just me trying everything. Good tip on the negative z-index, I got that from a random tutorial and I wasn't sure if it was an accepted use.